# Internet shortcut created second time not working

Tags: vbscript, shortcut

I have created URL shortcut in start menu with URL with IP:Port (https://199.158.25.55:1212). Following are the .url file for same.

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=https://199.158.25.55:1212/
IDList=
[{000214A0-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
Prop3=19,2
```

With this shortcut I can access the website above mentioned.

Now, I m deleting this file and creating same file with different port say 4545. So new file for same is

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=https://199.158.25.55:4545/
IDList=
[{000214A0-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
Prop3=19,2
```

When I tried to open the URL with start menu, the web browser URL shows previously created shortcut (https://199.158.25.55:1212 which is no more exists) and I m not able to access the site.

This is happening with Mozilla and Chrome web browsers. With IE it is working properly. After searching for long time, I haven't got any reason behind this.

Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks.

Comment: probably cookie or browsercache issue, but what has this to do with vbscript ?, it's not even about programming so not for stackoverflow, use one of the other stackexchange services